# Auto set datetime of new rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet.  What I am trying to do is when I click on a new row to automatically set the first column in the row to `=now()`.

I tried setting `=Now()` in the cell but it appears to be updating it all time time.

So I tried doing some kind of if statement.  IF the next cell is empty then I set the first cell to now.  If its not then I leave it to the original value.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(CONCAT("b",ROW())), NOW(), CONCAT("a",ROW()))
```

This didn't work as it becomes a circular reference.

Is there a way to configure my sheet so that the first column is always filled out with the current date? the time stamp of when the row was created.

Comment: so you are trying to add datetime stamp based on your statement or based on new row creation? - there is a difference. also... NOW(), TODAY() is a volatile type of function  which means it gets updated constantly unless you freeze it with a script or sophisticated formula statements

Comment: Exactly I just want new rows to be time stamped.    I tried adding a script but i dont want to have to run it all the time i would rather it just work as i type.

Comment: how about script that will populate first column with time stamp only each row you edit - would that satisfy you?

Comment: yup.  But can you set scripts to run on edit?

Comment: yeah, why not :) let me find the script you need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range
   .getSheet()
   .getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, e.range.getNumRows())
   .setValue(new Date())
   .setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yy, hh:mm:ss');
}
```

**[demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10tWO2Ym0RCEjapLtAlXnpgw-hk7ScRMXrspWEfvgPNk/edit#gid=0)**

or try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var date = new Date();

  var dates = sheet
      .getRange(row, 1, rows)
      .getValues()
      .map(function(row) {return [row[0] || date];});

  sheet
   .getRange(row, 1, rows)
   .setValues(dates)
   .setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yy, hh:mm:ss');
}
```

Comment: WOW.   Ok i am curious.  Are there other triggers like onEdit?  It must automatically  fire any scripts attached to the sheet?

Comment: one question if you have time.   Any way to get it to only update if its not already set to a date.  I only want it set when the row is first created not every time i edit the row.

Comment: @DaImTo you can check: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/ onEdit trigger will fire only for those scripts that are onEdit when you edit your sheet